# Not able to access Spring Security Logged in User info

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using Spring Security for authentication in my web-application.
Now, i need access to the User Information, for which the following method exists in the Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/userstuff")
@Controller
public class SomeUserController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "getUser", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public UserDetails getUser(Locale locale, Model model) {
        UserDetails userDetails = null;
        SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        Authentication authentication = securityContext.getAuthentication();
        if (authentication != null) {
            Object principal = authentication.getPrincipal();
            userDetails = (UserDetails) (principal instanceof UserDetails ? principal
                    : null);
        }
        return userDetails;
    }

}
```

IF the controller url is put out of security check like this in applicationContext-Security.xml:

```
<security:http pattern="/userstuff/**" security="none" />
```

Then invoking

http:// host:port /app/userstuff/getUser - **returns null**.

BUT, if do commented it out (allowing spring security to intercept it):

```
<!-- <security:http pattern="/userstuff/**" security="none" /> -->
```

Then invoking:
http:// host:port /app/userstuff/getUser **returns logged in user correctly**.

***Why so?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `security="none"` **all spring security filters will be switched off** (see [this entry](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#nsa-http-security) from the official documentation). So no `SecurityContextHolder`, no `@PreAuthorize`, no other Spring Security features are available. For example normally `SecurityContextHolder` is populated by one filter from security filter chain.

As a workaround almost always you can replace `security="none"` construction by restriction for anonymous user only:

```
<security:http ... />
    ...
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/userstuff/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    ....
</security:http>
```